# использование слайдера bxSlider в табах

Tags: jquery, slider

На странице несколько слайдеров bxSlider, один из них отображается при загрузке страницы и работает нормально. Остальные изначально скрыты, когда же должны стать видимыми - картинки не отображаются. Т.е. для этого слайдера необходимо, чтобы картинки при загрузке были видимыми, чтобы рассчитать их высоту. 
Вроде можно перезагружать слайдер в момент отображения вкладки, но браузер выдает ошибку: `slider.reloadSlider is not a function`

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Пример вот: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/3750/

Comment: Запихнула вызов слайдера в функцию, слайдер на вкладках начал отображаться. Правда он теперь подгружается каждый раз, когда функция вызывается. Помогите плиз переделать код так, чтобы инициализация слайдера происходила только один раз.http://jsfiddle.net/9ah84p6f/1/

Comment: Решение нашла. Добавляем к скрытым слайдерам класс 'active', а после инициализации слайдера удаляем этот класс. В итоге галерея подгружается корректно. http://jsfiddle.net/9ah84p6f/2/ Если есть решение изящней - буду благодарна за ваши варианты

Answer (score 2):

Решение нашла. Добавляем к скрытым слайдерам класс *'active'*, а после инициализации слайдера удаляем этот класс. В итоге галерея подгружается корректно. jsfiddle.net/9ah84p6f/2

Answer (score 0):

Все вызовы слайдера запихнула в скрипт, который "табами" управляет, но в самое его начало. После:

`$(document).ready(function()`

сначала все слайдеры запускаются, и уже потом:

```
 $(".tabs").hide()
```

и т.д.